# Review queue not showing answers marked as spam correctly

Tags: bug, reviewing

[Review queue in question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/320770)

While going through the review queue this morning, I noticed a bug when reviewing the linked duplicate. When viewing the [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164341/how-exactly-do-i-install-minecraft-mods-and-what-is-forge) normally, answers that have been marked as spam display correctly with the disclaimer text.

[image: Answers with spam text disclaimer]

However, while on the "Duplicate" tab in the review queue, answers that were marked as spam do not show correctly and you can see what was posted.

[image: Answers without spam text disclaimer]